# MVC5 Mailkit send email with incorrect Email address

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-5, mailkit

I am trying to send emails using my MVC5 application. To do this, I have installed Mailkit v 1.22.0 through NuGet package manager. And this is how my code looks like:

```
    var FromAddress = "no-reply@email.com";
    var FromAddressTitle = "My Org";
    var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SmtpServer"].ConnectionString;

    var Email = new MimeMessage();
    Email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAddressTitle, FromAddress));

    var AddressArray = value.SentTo.Split(';');
    foreach (var item in AddressArray)
    {
        Email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(item));
    }

    Email.Subject = value.Subject;        
    Email.Body = new TextPart("html")
    {
        Text = value.Content
    };

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect(connection);
        client.Send(Email);
    }

    return "Email Successfully Sent";
```

which works fine except if a wrong recipient Email address has been entered, the application does not detect if the Email was actually sent or not (client.Send(Email) returns void). Is there a way to know if it really ended up getting sent to the recipient or not? If it is not possible with Mailkit, is there any other NuGet package that can do this?

Comment: Best way to go here is to use an external service, such as [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com), which has facilities to process and handle bounces.

Comment: @A J Can you please post your connection string, I am trying to get Mimekit to work on MVC project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that SmtpClient.Send() returns void is that the SMTP protocol does not specify whether the message gets delivered successfully. All it can do us tell the client that the messages was accepted by the server or not (in which case MailKit will throw an exception).

If you need to know whether the message was successfully delivered, you will need to check for bounce messages sent to you which could take minutes or even hours.

The first thing you'll have to do, however, is subclass `SmtpClient` and override the [GetEnvelopeId](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_GetEnvelopeId.htm) and [GetDeliveryStatusNotifications](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_GetDeliveryStatusNotifications.htm) methods.

Then, when you receive a bounce message, the top-level MIME part will typically be a `multipart/report` (represented by a `MultipartReport` object when using MimeKit). This `multipart/report` will then contain a `message/delivery-status` MIME part (and possibly others), which will have a list of header-like fields that specify the details about the delivery status for 1 or more recipients.

MimeKit will parse a lot of this for you (e.g. it has a [MessageDeliveryStatus](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MessageDeliveryStatus.htm) class which contains a [StatusGroups](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MimeKit_MessageDeliveryStatus_StatusGroups.htm) property that you will want to use. However, what MimeKit does *not* do is parse the individual field values (but they shouldn't be that difficult for you to do, typically a few `Split(';')`'s should be enough iirc for some quick & dirty parsing).

You will want to read the spec for this at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464

The MimeKit docs linked above specify which sections to look closely at (I think 2.2 and 2.3).

I would recommend looking specifically at the `Original-Recipient` and `Action` fields.

```
  original-recipient-field =
         "Original-Recipient" ":" address-type ";" generic-address

  generic-address = *text

  action-field = "Action" ":" action-value

  action-value =
        "failed" / "delayed" / "delivered" / "relayed" / "expanded"
```

You will also need the `Original-Envelope-Id` field to figure out which message is being reported on:

```
   original-envelope-id-field =
              "Original-Envelope-Id" ":" envelope-id

   envelope-id = *text
```

The `envelope-id` text will be the same string returned by your `GetEnvelopeId` implementation in the `SmtpClient` class.